# Update using left join in netezza

Tags: left-join, insert-update, netezza

I need to perform a left join of two tables in netezza during an update. How can i achieve this ? Left join with three tables are working but not with two tables.

```
UPDATE table_1
SET c2 = t2.c2
FROM
    table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2.t1
    ON t1.c1=t2.c1
    LEFT JOIN table_3 t3
    ON t2.c1=t3.c1
```

this works but

```
UPDATE table_1
SET c2 = t2.c2
FROM table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2.t1
    ON t1.c1=t2.c1
```

this says like trying to update multiple columns.

Thanks,
Manirathinam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing an UPDATE TABLE with a join in Netezza, it's important to understand that the table being updated is *always* implicitly INNER JOINed with the FROM list.  This behavior is [documented here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_update.html).

Your code is actually joining table_1 to itself (one copy with no alias, and one with t1 as an alias). Since there is no join criteria between those two versions of table_1, you are getting a cross join which is providing multiple rows that are trying to update table_1.

The best way to tackle an UPDATE with an OUTER join is to employ a subselect like this:

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from table_1 order by c1;
 C1 | C2
----+----
  1 |  1
  2 |  2
  3 |  3
(3 rows)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from table_2 order by c1;
 C1 | C2
----+----
  1 | 10
  3 | 30
(2 rows)


TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> UPDATE table_1 t1
SET t1.c2 = foo.c2
FROM (
      SELECT t1a.c1,
         t2.c2
      FROM table_1 t1a
         LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
         ON t1a.c1 = t2.c1
   )
   foo
WHERE t1.c1 = foo.c1;
UPDATE 3

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from table_1 order by c1;
 C1 | C2
----+----
  1 | 10
  2 |
  3 | 30
(3 rows)
```